# How to find out, which screen is HEAD-0, HEAD-1, etc.?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, display, multi-monitor

If I want to use the name of my primary screen (HDMI-0, found out via `xrandr`) within another command, the device is never found.

Instead I have to use the name HEAD-0. From what I've already read I assume this is probably a nVidia-thing, but I don't understand how it works, why it's done and most importantly:

How can I find out, which of my screens has which HEAD-name?

Comment: Which tool is it that uses these `HEAD-x` names?

Comment: @Score_Under I'm currently using the `setxwacom` command to setup my Huion tablet

Comment: I don't know where to go from here either unfortunately. Seems like back in 2008 the nvidia driver did not support XRandR properly, but it has since improved. All I can suggest is to make sure you're on the latest nvidia drivers, and if not, see if the nouveau ones work better for your use case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just out if curiosity, is AMD this troublesome as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the correct answer, but you can query connected displays via `nvidia-settings --query dpys`.

If I understand it correctly, `HEAD-x` is mapped to a display of the output of `nvidia-settings` in the order they appear. For example: `HEAD-0` is the first connected display, `HEAD-3` the fourth, etc.